# Different compatibility versions on different source sets

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a project which should be compatible with Java `1.6` (to ensure that it can be used in android as well). The tests for this project on the other hand are allowed to use the full 1.8 feature set. So `main/java/` should be compiled to `1.6`, `test/java` to `1.8`. How can this be configured.

When I configure the compatibility levels, this affects also the tests. How can this be configured per sourceset?

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.6'
targetCompatibility = '1.6'

compileJava {
    options.fork = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way :

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.6'
    targetCompatibility = '1.6'
}


compileTestJava {
  sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
  targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}
```

so when you will compile your test it will be to `java 1.8`, and when you compile your `src` it will be for `java 1.6`

Comment: Thanks. That's it.